# Converting the value of Vrms to A/sqrt(Hz)

Tags: power, noise

I am taking data by passing the current of the source through a 1 Ohm resistor and measuring the voltage over the resistor with a SRS-SR760 FFT spectrum analyzer. SRS-SR760 FFT giving me values in Vrms (nVrms, uVrms, pVrms) but I want to convert this in A/sqrt(Hz), I know Ohm law giving us V = I R, in my case it should be Vrms = Arms 1 Ohm (because I am using 1 Ohm resistor). But I don't have any idea that how I bring 
Vrms --?(to)--> Arms/sqrt(Hz) 
Can anyone help me to guide that /sqrt(Hz)?

Thanks

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with Vrms, apparently?  You have Arms and want something derived from it?  What's the point of mentioning Vrms at all?

Answer (score 1):

Switch the spectrum analyzer to show the power spectral density (PSD). The display will be normalized to 1Hz bandwidth in \$V/\sqrt{\text{Hz}}\$, which in your case is equivalent to \$A/\sqrt{\text{Hz}}\$

The FFT display you are looking now at is the RMS signal amplitude in each frequency bin.

It's often a good ideal to familiarize yourself with complex instruments by reading the manual and performing a few simple exercises to understand what it is doing.